# Почему не получается получить значение реквизита формы в 1С?

Tags: 1с

Я сделал форму, добавил реквизит пользователей из справочника пользователей и создал поле выбора с типом справочника пользователей. Мне нужно получить значение этого реквизита в модуле формы, но в строке, где я его получаю, выходит ошибка:

```
Ошибка при вызове метода контекста (РеквизитФормыВЗначение)
{Отчеты Отчет.НовыйОтчетПрофилей.Форма.ФормаОтчета.Форма(201)}:РеквизитПользователя = РеквизитФормыВЗначение("Пользователь"); //
{Отчеты Отчет.НовыйОтчетПрофилей.Форма.ФормаОтчета.Форма(230)}:ТабДокумент                          = СформироватьМакетНаСервере();

по причине:
Недопустимое значение параметра (параметр номер '1')
```

Как это можно исправить?

Вот сам код:

```
&НаСервере
Функция СформироватьМакетНаСервере()
    
    ОтчетОбъект = РеквизитФормыВЗначение("Отчет"); 
    РеквизитПользователя = РеквизитФормыВЗначение("Пользователь"); //
    
    КомпоновщикМакета = Новый КомпоновщикМакетаКомпоновкиДанных;
    
    МакетКомпоновкиДанных = КомпоновщикМакета.Выполнить(ОтчетОбъект.СхемаКомпоновкиДанных,  ОтчетОбъект.КомпоновщикНастроек.Настройки, , ,  Тип("ГенераторМакетаКомпоновкиДанныхДляКоллекцииЗначений"));
    
    ПроцессорКомпоновкиДанных = Новый ПроцессорКомпоновкиДанных;
    ПроцессорКомпоновкиДанных.Инициализировать(МакетКомпоновкиДанных);
    
    ПроцессорВывода = Новый ПроцессорВыводаРезультатаКомпоновкиДанныхВКоллекциюЗначений;
    
    ТаблицаЗначений = Новый ТаблицаЗначений;
    ПроцессорВывода.УстановитьОбъект(ТаблицаЗначений);
    ПроцессорВывода.Вывести(ПроцессорКомпоновкиДанных); 
        
    ТабДокумент = Новый ТабличныйДокумент;
    
    ТабДокумент.Очистить();
    Макет = ОтчетОбъект.ПолучитьМакет("Макет");
                                            
    Возврат ТабДокумент;
    
КонецФункции

&НаКлиенте
Процедура СформироватьМакет(Команда)
    
    ТабДокумент                         = СформироватьМакетНаСервере();    
    КоллекцияПечатныхФорм               = УправлениеПечатьюКлиент.НоваяКоллекцияПечатныхФорм("Макет");
    ПечатнаяФорма                       = УправлениеПечатьюКлиент.ОписаниеПечатнойФормы(КоллекцияПечатныхФорм, "Макет");
    ПечатнаяФорма.СинонимМакета         = "Макет";
    ПечатнаяФорма.ТабличныйДокумент     = ТабДокумент;
    ПечатнаяФорма.ИмяФайлаПечатнойФормы = "Макет";
    
    ОбластиОбъектов = Новый СписокЗначений;
    УправлениеПечатьюКлиент.ПечатьДокументов(КоллекцияПечатныхФорм, ОбластиОбъектов);
    
КонецПроцедуры
```

Вот форма со свойствами поля:

[image]

И свойства реквизита:

[image]

Comment: Реквизит формы добавили?

Comment: @Sagittarius в реквизитах формы добавил реквизит с типом ссылки справочника пользователей и перенес этот реквизит на форму - получилось поле выбора

Comment: Как в прошлый раз - сделайте скриншот, и добавьте к вопросу; Чтобы было видно точное Имя реквизита

Comment: @santavital добавил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Директива `&НаСервере` перед `Функция СформироватьМакетНаСервере()` означает что функция выполняется на сервере и ... доступен *Контекст* (т.е. все реквизиты формы)

Обратиться к реквизиту формы в этом случае можно по имени :

```
РеквизитПользователя = Пользователь;
РеквизитПользователя = ЭтаФорма.Пользователь; // То же самое, но с подсказкой после точки
```

Comment: Писать "ЭтаФорма" ненужно. Реквизиты формы и так видны на клиенте и на сервере.